# How to find my saved locations in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I have lots of favorite locations (starred locations) in Google Maps. It's visible on the map as I scroll/drag to it. But isn't there a place where all the saved locations/coordinates are listed?

I remember the older version of Maps having it on the side bar. This is how the latest versions side bar looks:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran today in the same problem. It seems that Google decided to hide a list of saved places in order to force people to activate places history. Maybe I found a workaround. Log in your Google account and go to your [Google bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/)—you should see your saved places.

Comment: Thank you. But that's a bad decision that google took. It should be integrated seemlessly with the Maps interface.

Comment: Funny thing is that in mobile version of Google Maps application, saved places are first thing in the side bar

Comment: +1 Wow- how many years have I been using Google and Maps and never knew there was a Google Bookmarks that is totally separate from Chrome Bookmarks? Sometimes Google makes things way too difficult and unintuitive. A small price to pay for the free and awesome map and navigation service, that's for sure. I now have Google Bookmarks bookmarked in my Chrome Bookmarks- seems redundant but there you have it!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like Google recently added that feature again. Last time I checked (2016-05-31), you can select "Your Places" and then switch to the "Saved" tab:

[image: Saved places within Google Maps]

Comment: Works for me, but the initial menu entry says "Your places" rather than "My places".

Comment: Oh, thanks for the correction, I've edited the answer accordingly :) I use the German version where the label is "Meine Orte" which translates to "My places" but anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can find saved places in the Android Google Maps application by touching the menu on upper left side of the map (three lines) and selecting "Your Places". It will show you the places you've saved in Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

You can see saved places visually by scrolling out - they show up as Stars. Still bad though if you're looking by name and do not want to have to retype it.